# Show Sub-task's parent Story on JIRA Dashboard using Filter Query

Tags: jira, dashboard, jql, kanban

I have a Kanban Software Project in JIRA Cloud. I use Stories with Sub-tasks to separate different things that have to be done.

On a dashboard, I use a Filter Results gadget to show Issues. The Sub-tasks are shown in a format as such:

```
ABC-13 / Sub-task summary
```

...where `ABC-13` is the Story key. I would like to be able see the actual Story name (summary) in the Dashboard. Either in the same column as the Sub-task (replacing the Story key) or in a separate column.

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a semi-hacky workaround that does work a charm. It includes overwriting some of JIRA's CSS to show the title attribute, using a Google Chrome extension.

1. Download Stylebot from the Chrome Web Store
2. Go to your JIRA dashboard, open Stylebot and click Edit CSS.
3. Paste the following CSS:

---

```
a.issue-link.parentIssue::after {
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1.4em;
}

a.issue-link.parentIssue {
    opacity: 0;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

a.issue-link:not(.parentIssue) {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This will hide the key and add it's own `title` attribute as a CSS:after pseudo element. To differentiate between the sub-task and it's parent, the subtask is made bold.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it.
If you mouse over the parent issue key, it shows summary for the parent issue in the tooltip. It is not so useful.

There is an old feature request for [Jira Server](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-16589) or for [Cloud](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-16589).
You can check the comments and upvote the request.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following advanced query to display parent issues of tasks assigned to me:

issueFunction in parentsOf("status in (Open, 'In progress') AND project = MPONE AND assignee in (currentUser())") ORDER BY key ASC

You can add the sub-task column to get the issue link for the tasks themselves.

I have not found a way to display both the part